# How to render views dynamically for restaurant table selection?

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, selection

I want to have the dynamic creation of the views on a layout in android. The layout basically is for the restaurant table selection. So it will be different for each restaurant.

I actually came across one app which has the same layout which I need but I don't get any idea by just seeing that. [here is the screen-shot of it](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/z9RCe8lJZ-Z0Wat1ZJGRL_2VS6Yxt38Vrev8g1aV8RscVnPcwAlb0gE-Q7UhMRvr-rE=h900-rw)

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!